# How can re-use the index value from one section to another one? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace the [0] for the index value obtained in the code above.
The data[0] is coming from a Json file, and the index value is coming from the month selection.
So my goal is to update the data coming from JSON file after the user select a month from the drop down menu.

//Getting the index after selecting a month:

```
months.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.onclick = function () {
    const indexValue = Number(index);
    const monthSelected = (monthText.textContent = this.innerHTML);
    console.log(monthSelected);
    console.log(indexValue);
    return indexValue;
  };
});
```

[image]

//Here's is where I need to change that hard coded 0 for something:

```
// Step2
const jsonData = fetch("data.json")
  .then(function (resp) {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    const generalData = data[0];
```

Trying to re-use the index inside the []

Comment: There is nowhere to return the value to. So `someElement.innerHTML = generalData[indexValue];` would work better than the return

Comment: Please click [edit] then the `[<>]` snippet editor and replace the fetch with an example generalData in a [mcve]

Comment: If you want to fetch data every time the user selects a value, you need to put the data-fetching code inside the event handler. Where you can trivially access the `indexValue`.

Comment: What does the returned JSON look like? It also seems like if you made your fetch return the parsed JSON, then you could reference the data object in your click event handler, not the other way around.

Comment: You are missing too much code/information here for anyone to really help. It looks like either you should store the JSON data in a global variable so you can call it from the click event handler instead, or you should just loop through your `months` variable again (like you did in step 1) to get and set each data index. Your first loop seems to be only for setting a click event listener, but you apparently also need to loop through it to set data to be displayed.

Comment: i know there some code that I decided not to show for business reasons, but What i'm gonna do is, i'm gonna try to do som DOM manipulation inside of fetching Json data section, so from there to use the index given by the Json data file.

Comment: I'll keep you posted guys, thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I did it guys!!! , well, the main goal of this project was to update the UI info inside the cards after selecting any given month. As you can see in the SS.
Now I have to find out how to solve another challenges on this project.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTiwV.png)

Answer (score -1):

I would just set it as global variable.

```
months.forEach((el, index) => {
  el.onclick = function () {
    var indexValue = Number(index);
    const monthSelected = (monthText.textContent = this.innerHTML);
    console.log(monthSelected);
    console.log(indexValue);
  };
});
```

Then would use it as index for data array.

```
// Step2
const jsonData = fetch("data.json")
  .then(function (resp) {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    const generalData = data[indexValue];
```

Comment: This doesn't work..., The outcome: 'indexValue is not define'

Comment: It's not defined because step 1 was not called and line  `var indexValue = Number(index);` was not executed.  You didn't say what's relation between the steps, so I just corrected what I could.